# "В конце концов". Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужно ли обособить "в конце концов" в данном случае: "В конце концов надо решить вопрос с твоей учёбой"?

Мне кажется, что нужно, но я немного сомневаюсь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**В КОНЦЕ КОНЦОВ**, *вводное сочетание*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_282)

> Выражает недовольство, нетерпение, раздражение или указывает на то,
> что соотносящееся с ним высказывание является заключительным. Подробно
> о пунктуации при вводных словах и сочетаниях [см. в Прил. 2.](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2)
>
> *Мне это надоело, **в конце концов**.* А. Чехов, Чайка. *Не насильно же ее, **в конце концов,** тащить!..* Е. Шкловский, Противостояние.
> *…Этот визит занял весь вечер и напрочь разрушил столь любимое им чувство одиночества. **В конце концов,** может, и хорошо, что
> разрушил: одиночество тоже с каких-то пор перестало быть для него
> спасением, как не было им и многолюдье.* В. Быков, Бедные люди.
>
> **! Не смешивать** с употреблением в роли члена предложения (в знач. «после всего, в завершение, напоследок»).
>
> ***В конце концов** елка обирается и публика расходится...* А. Чехов, Елка. *…Неужели я всё-таки забуду его в какой-то короткий срок – ведь
> всё в **конце концов** забывается?* И. Бунин, Холодная осень.

---

[**Вопрос № 285609**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=285609)

> Здравствуйте. Обязательна ли запятая перед «в конце концов»? Или
> возможны оба варианта? Уйдешь ты или нет, в конце концов?
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Запятую надо поставить. Слова в конце концов, выражающие недовольство,
> нетерпение, раздражение, обособляются как вводные.

---

Лена, в Вашем предложении запятая зависит от вкладываемого смысла - он выражен интонацией.

*В конце концов надо решить вопрос с твоей учёбой*, - в завершение всего, последнее, что "нам" надо решить, - запятая не нужна.

*В конце концов, надо решить вопрос с твоей учёбой*, - хватит заниматься поисками себя, тянуть кота за хвост и ходить вокруг да около, - налицо раздражение с нетерпением, обосновывающие постановку запятой.